# Updating iOS native dependencies with pod install - failed! update ios - failed! Error in Mac M1

Tags: reactjs, xcode, ionic2

In Convert the Web app (React) to mobile app. at the time i used "npx cap sync" command in my terminal. android created ,but ios not created it's shown the below error.

✔ Copying web assets from build to android/app/src/main/assets/public in 50.44ms
✔ Creating capacitor.config.json in android/app/src/main/assets in 454.25μs
✔ copy android in 69.14ms
✔ Copying web assets from build to ios/App/App/public in 37.42ms
✔ Creating capacitor.config.json in ios/App/App in 154.92μs
✔ copy ios in 44.92ms
✔ copy web in 3.15ms
juhomi@juhomis-MacBook-Air coracloud-react % npx cap sync
✔ Copying web assets from build to android/app/src/main/assets/public in 41.18ms
✔ Creating capacitor.config.json in android/app/src/main/assets in 1.61ms
✔ copy android in 55.22ms
✔ Updating Android plugins in 3.34ms
✔ update android in 16.99ms
✔ Copying web assets from build to ios/App/App/public in 39.34ms
✔ Creating capacitor.config.json in ios/App/App in 176.75μs
✔ copy ios in 46.52ms
✔ Updating iOS plugins in 3.09ms
✖ Updating iOS native dependencies with pod install - failed!
✖ update ios - failed!
[error] Ignoring json-2.5.1 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine json --version 2.5.1
Ignoring ffi-1.15.0 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.15.0
internal:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require': linked to incompatible /Users/juhomi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/libruby.2.7.dylib - /Users/juhomi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/date-3.3.3/lib/date_core.bundle (LoadError) from <internal:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in` require'
from /Users/juhomi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/date-3.3.3/lib/date.rb:4:in `<top (required)>' from <internal:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in` require'
from internal:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in
`require' from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/time.rb:4:in` <top (required)>'
from internal:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in
`require' from <internal:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in` require'
from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/gh_inspector-1.1.3/lib/gh_inspector/evidence.rb:2:in
`<top (required)>' from <internal:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in` require'
from internal:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in
`require' from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/gh_inspector-1.1.3/lib/gh_inspector.rb:4:in` <top
(required)>'
from internal:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in
`require' from <internal:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in` require'
from
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:5:in
`<top (required)>' from <internal:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in` require'
from internal:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in
`require' from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:1:in` <top (required)>'
from internal:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in
`require' from <internal:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in` require'
from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods.rb:30:in `<module:Pod>' from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods.rb:17:in` <top
(required)>'
from internal:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in
`require' from <internal:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in` require'
from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/bin/pod:36:in `<top (required)>' from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/bin/pod:25:in` load'
from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/bin/pod:25:in `'

Note : My PC OS - Mac (M1) (Ventura 13.2.1)